# Dúvidas com função de IP

Tags: php, ip

Utilizo a seguinte função abaixo para buscar o Ip do usuário, independente do tipo de conexão ou dispositivo que o mesmo utiliza.

```
  function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if ( isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' ] ) )
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' ];
else if ( isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' ] ) )
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' ];
else if ( isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED' ] ) )
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED' ];
else if ( isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR' ] ) )
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR' ];
else if ( isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_FORWARDED' ] ) )
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_FORWARDED' ];
else if ( isset( $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ] ) )
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ];
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

return $ipaddress;
 }
```

Funciona perfeitamente. Ele registra o IP do usuário em uma tabela mysql.

Resolvi fazer um teste, dando um echo na página PHP, conforme mostrado abaixo, para então ele exibir o IP do usuário.

```
 echo get_client_ip();
```

Quando utilizo um dipositivo com acesso wi-fi, ele exibe o IP normalmente.
O problema é que, ao acessar esta mesma pagina PHP através de um celular usando 'dados móveis', ao invés de exibir o IP do mesmo, ele exibe outra informação, como mostrada abaixo e não o seu real IP:

```
 2804:d45:b18:94bc::1
```

O curioso é que ele salva o IP normalmente (e não essa informação como mostrada acima), somente quando peço para dar o echo acima, ele exibe desta maneira. Poderiam me explicar por quê?

Comment: Não tem como capturar o IP real da maquina, se vc testar em qualquer site de rastreio de ip, vai ter capturado o ip do servidor, não da maquina, usei essa mesma função achando q estava certo

Comment: Mas `2804:d45:b18:94bc::1` é um IPv6, qual IP ele salva no MySQL?

Comment: Hm, ele estava salvando em IPv4